# Upgrading 2021 Giant Roam 2 Disc (wheels, groupset, chain)

Tags: mountain-bike, touring, upgrades, gravel, groupsets

I'm planning to upgrade my 2021 Giant Roam 2 Disc. Not looking at high-end components. Hope someone could verify if these parts will fit? Also appreciate recommendations for wheels. In case I missed any components that also need to be changed by my planned upgrades please let me know as well. Thanks!

My bike - https://www.giant-bicycles.com/us/roam-2-disc-2021

Components I plan to upgrade

1. Wheels (upgrading to tubeless) - Needs to be tubeless, occasional weekender long distance rides, maybe some bike touring, 70% road 30% gravel. Not sure if bike will be able to accommodate 650b tires (without upgrading the rims). Not even sure if 650b makes sense. I'm about 5'6 and the bike size I use is Medium.

2. Groupset: Cassette, Rear Derailleur, Shifters (upgrading from 9 to 10) 

Cassette - [Microshift | Advent X Cassette | 10-Speed | 11-48t | Black | Alloy Spider](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08615MTV6)

Rear Derailleur - [microSHIFT | Advent X Rear Derailleur | 10-Speed | Medium Cage | Black | with Clutch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B086165JQW)

Shifters - [Microshift | Advent X Trail Trigger Pro Right Shifter | 1x10 Speed | Thumb Pad | Advent X Compatible Only](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08615Z4WT)

3. Chain (because upgrading from 9 to 10) - [KMC X10-116L, NP/BK 10 Speed Bicycle Chain](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001AYOP9M)

[image]

References

1. https://www.cyclingtips.com/2022/08/a-guide-to-freehub-body-and-cassette-compatibility/
2. https://www.giantbikespares.com/browse_by_model/2021-Roam-2

Comment: Worth reading the Q/A's we have around upgrading vs selling/buying  (use search) e.g. https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/74343/upgrading-a-entry-level-hybrid-bike-or-purchasing-a-new-better-one

Comment: Will do. Thanks @mattnz!

Comment: @bubblemaker I posted an update in the linked question, you may be interested.

Comment: @Renaud, I just checked it out and saved your post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend you to check on the bike, instead of looking at the spec sheet. It looked very strange to me: the picture shows a derailleur that looks like a RD-M5120, which is the cheapest Deore clutched derailleur. But this derailleur cannot be used with 9 speed shifters and 9 speed cassettes. It's not the first time that Giant is not very accurate in their specifications.

I did a quick search and found [a video showing a review of Roam 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NNk2cKVQqpg). This video shows a RD-M5120, but fitted with a 11/46 cassette 10 speed, that is totally within the specs. If it's confirmed on your bike, changing it for an Advent X won't be an "upgrade", the two groupsets are almost equivalent (the 2T difference is not worth the "upgrade" in my opinion).

For the wheels/tires, we don't do product recommendations here (the goal is to make a knowledge base, recommendations tend to be outdated quite fast, and depend on the region). But as a general recommendation, in this segment, replacing only the rims will be as expensive (if not more) than buying a new wheelset. The best is to search among gravel wheels, that are inline with the bike use. Note that gravel bikes often have thru-axles, but some brands offer the possibility to change end caps on the hubs, and fit adapters to use them on bikes with quick release.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that great feedback. You're absolutely correct! It's a 10 speed with an 11x46t cassette. I trusted the spec sheet and never bothered checking the bike. =( Noted on the wheels/tires as well.